# Why does this happen with this wordpress theme?

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I've been trying to figure it out for a while why this happens. 
If you visit "http://adslabmedia.com/freestuff/" and scroll down, you will see that Product Testing and The Sun Trial are not aligned. I do not understand why this happens, I've created these boxes using a builder, so there is nothing I could have done wrong. All from the same page are being made in the same manner.

Here are the atributes I have regarding to these "promo boxes":
Attributes:

- Image (upload photo for Promo Box item - can be on right or left side)
- Title (title for Progress Box item);
- Content (content for Progress    box item);
- Button Text (type text for the button inside Progress Box item)
- Button Link (link for the button)
- Image position (choose between left or right side position for image
  above)
- Border (choose if you want to show border on right hand side or not)
- Open in new window (choose if you want  to open link in new window or
  not)
- Animation (choose entrance animation on scroll or leave without
  animation)

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the result of the box one row above to the left. Because the Headline  `<h2>Quotezon Free Bike Insurance Quote</h2>` is displayed in two rows, the box has more height than the box to the right (on my laptop 9px). Therefore the "Sun Trial" doesn't fit on the left side and is displayed to the right. I've just tested what happens when the headline is reduced to `<h2>Quotezon Free Bike</h2>` - then "Sun Trial" is displayed on the left side and "Product Testing" on the right side in the next row.
Depending on the screen size, this does not only happen with the "Sun Trial" - on my screen the same applies to the 2nd row with "Coupon XPlorer" (single box on the right) and "Primark" in the next row to the left. Maybe you can adjust the CSS to have a min height for all boxes.

Comment: This works to expand on it you need .one-second.column {
min-height: 20em;
}

Comment: I stand corrected but that min height worked for me at least.

Answer (score 0):

The box is created incorrectly. For some reason all of its html tags have the word title at the end of the open tag.

```
<div class="column one-second column_promo_box" title="">
    <div class="promo_box no_border" title="">
        <div class="animate zoomInDown" data-anim-type="zoomInDown" title="">
```

Is a small sample of it, I would guess something went wrong in the generation of it.

EDIT:

When looking at the other boxes that are formatted correctly the code is different so that's why I assume they were generated incorrectly.

Comment: I have regenerated them and they are still being show in a wrong way.

Comment: See matthias_h's answer